# Anaconda failed to install

Tags: windows, anaconda

I'm trying to install anaconda python 3.7.0 (on intel pentium with 2 GB ram and windows xp professional)

I've downloaded anaconda python `x64` and tried to install it but a error message came

> X32 bit system doesn' t support this installer,for help see the
>   support page

Then I've tried installing `x32` bit installer but it did not install well the navigator did not work and a error message came in browser and i cant find jupyter notebook and spyder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dhana
Your Computer Does not support anaconda python distribution because anaconda python requires windows 7 and above.

So i consider you to try upgrading the computer OS from windows xp to windows 7 or 8 or 8.1 or 10.

Once u upgraded the os, anaconda will work

Best of luck
The_py_prog